# Should we kill [tag:teamfight-tactics] and repoint it to [tag:league-of-legends]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, sub-tags

League of Legends just released a game mode called Teamfight Tactics. It is played through the LoL client, using LoL assets. Someone has created [teamfight-tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teamfight-tactics) and it has 3 questions that I can see. Should we create a tag synonym and point it to [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) instead?

Comment: There's definitely precedent for 'different game mode' style tags. Fortnite and GTA V have split tags between game modes, TF2 has [tag:tf2-mann-vs-machine] etc. I don't play LoL, but if the community thinks it's a useful subcategory of the main tag (i.e. it's different enough in gameplay, strategy and tactics to warrant filtering or splitting it from the main game) it could be useful. It could be potentially renamed to `[league-of-legends-teamfight-tactics]` which just scrapes under the tag length limit of 35

Comment: TFT is basically a hybrid card/strategy game. It has **significantly** different gameplay

Comment: Why was this question flagged as unclear? It seems both clear and relevant to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't believe we should make it a synonym for [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) as the game play is vastly different for TFT than for any other game mode in League of Legends. It is essentially a different game, it just so happens to be playable through the league client. Given that we have precedent for this in other games such as Fortnite, GTA V, TF2, et cetera, I would say we should keep the separate tag for the separate game.

I do think renaming the tag to [league-of-legends-teamfight-tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends-teamfight-tactics) to match the naming conventions for other tags we have such as [gta-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-online), [fortnite-save-the-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortnite-save-the-world), and others.

Comment: I think the tag should stay, but is there really a reason to keep "League of Legends" in the tag's name? Teamfight Tactics seems to be marketed as its own game, reusing League's assets but otherwise sharing nothing between the two. I don't think there's any ambiguity in just calling it "Teamfight Tactics". The fact that the tag was born as just "Teamfight Tactics" seems pretty telling to me, as well.

Comment: @Wrigglenite mainly due to the fact that all news for the game is on the [league site](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/featured/events/teamfight-tactics) and you have to download the league of legends client to play the game. If it used a separate client and had a separate site, I wouldn't recommend keeping "League of Legends" in the tag name

Answer (score 2):

I definitely agree with @Dragonrage's answer that those should be two different tags.

I've played a lot of League but I haven't touched TFT so far. When I first read some questions about TFT I was extremely confused about the things being asked here.

Adding TFT as a synonym to the existing LoL tag would cause a lot of confusion since the characters and items are the same but the strategies and the gameplay itself are completely different.

Having two different tags will allow for easier distinction especially if someone chooses to ignore one of the games.